# Keras KeyError: 'metrics' line ---> 13 callbacks=callbacks while executing model.fit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, keyerror

I was trying out this course in Coursera when I stumbled upon this problem. Whenever I try to run the model.fit() it shows this error.

## Error shown:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-83-0ef54ef3afb9> in <module>()
     11     validation_steps = len(x_val) // batch_size,
     12     epochs=12,
---> 13     callbacks=callbacks
     14 )

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/livelossplot/generic_keras.py in on_train_begin(self, logs)
     29 
     30     def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
---> 31         self.liveplot.set_metrics([metric for metric in self.params['metrics'] if not metric.startswith('val_')])
     32 
     33         # slightly convolved due to model.complie(loss=...) stuff

KeyError: 'metrics'
```

---

## **Here is my actual Code:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout,Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling2D

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

## Initialising the CNN

```
model = Sequential()
```

## 1st Convolution

```
model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5), padding='same', input_shape=(64, 128, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

## 2nd Convolution layer

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5,5), padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

## Flattening

```
model.add(Flatten())
```

## Fully connected layer

```
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

## Learning Rate Scheduling and Compile the Model

```
initial_learning_rate=0.005
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate = initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=5,
    decay_rate=0.96,
    staircase=True
)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer , metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
```

## Training the Model

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model_weight.h5', monitor='val_loss', 
                             save_weights_only=True, mode='min', verbose=0)
callbacks=[PlotLossesCallback(), checkpoint]

batch_size=32

history = model.fit(
    datagen_train.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True),
    steps_per_epoch = len(x_train) // batch_size,
    validation_data = datagen_val.flow(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True),
    validation_steps = len(x_val) // batch_size,
    epochs=12,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The exception is thrown inside a package that you are mentioning (the livelossplot), check if that package actually supports the version of tf.keras you have

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/stared/livelossplot/issues/104

Comment: From the source video where I was following from the instructor was using Tensorflow 2.1 while I am using 2.2, will that cause a problem?

Comment: Thank you, guys I tried out the given link, still no help, I think I might have to downgrade my version to match up with the Code to 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your import statement

```
from livelossplot.tf_keras import PlotLossesCallback
```

to

```
from livelossplot.inputs.tf_keras import PlotLossesCallback
```

Answer (score 2):

`livelossplot.tf_keras` will not work in Tensorflow version 2.1+, Downgrade your TensorFlow version from 2.2 to Tensorflow 2.1 using `pip install tensorflow==2.1`, it will work and plot your model training plots.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update `livelossplot` to work with tensorflow 2.x versions. There are major changes in working latest API. Instead of using `tf_keras` use `PlotLossesKeras`.

```
from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras

model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
          callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras()],
          verbose=0)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! The problem was solved using a proper import statement and Tensorflow version.